# Can't install Mono for Android for Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, mono, xamarin.android

When i try and install Mono for Android it won't install the plugin for Visual Studio. I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2010. Also when reading the installer log it shows an error when downloading the installer manifest.

```
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.386] [Info] Retrieving installer manifest.
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.386] [Info] Downloading from 'http://xamarin.com/download/InstallerManifest.xml'.
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Exception] Failed to download installer manifest from 'http://xamarin.com/download/InstallerManifest.xml'
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Exception] System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Exception] at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Exception] at WindowsInstaller.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`3 doDownload)
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Exception] at WindowsInstaller.Utilities.GetInstallerManifest()
[2011-11-30 09:03:00.688] [Info] Installer manifest not found at 'http://xamarin.com/download/InstallerManifest.xml'`
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

**Edit**

I've downloaded the windows installer from the beta releases on http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_1/Release_1.9.0. From there you can download the Visual Studio plugin directly. This shouldn't be the way to install the plugin but for an easy workaround it's good enough.

Comment: I think this documentation link will work ...Just go to this link and do a manual install...Its actually better: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows/Manual_Installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've notified the people at Xamarin about this issue, it should be resolved shortly.

Comment: I have sent them an email to but have yet to hear back from them.

Comment: grendel is the guy that wrote the installer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. The installer uses its built-in copy of the manifest, you can safely ignore the exception.
As for the VS not seeing the plugin - did you restart the IDE? If yes, then also make sure that the plugin was able to find the copy of Android SDK installed by the installer.

marek

Comment: I tried installing mono droid on an other computer. I had the same result there. See the edit for one solution.

Comment: Aidan, we still don't know what is the problem - how do you tell the plugin is not installed? Are there any other errors in the installation log? Does it not show up in VS options? Does VS report any errors?

Comment: The installation log doesn't contain any other errors. But it doesn't even try to install the VS plugin. When i go to the extension manager it doesn't show up either.

Comment: Does the following directory exist on your machine? c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Mono for Android\1.2.0.26415

Comment: No it didn't exist. Now i have installed a preview release (1.9.2) the directory does contain a directory named 1.9.0.26415. The plugin works for me now yet it didn't get installed using the installer for version 1.2.0.

Comment: It's a shame we don't get any errors from the process - I would love to know why the msi reportedly completed without error and yet the add-in isn't there.

Comment: I'll try and install it on another machine i've got with the same software. I wil post the entire log for you to see.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. On my other machine the visual studio plugin did get installed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i've found the installation log: http://pastebin.com/9dKW1DH4. Hope this can give you an idea of whats wrong.